# $f(a)+f(-b)=0$ implies $f(-a)+f(b)=0$. Then $f$ is an odd function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations, even-and-odd-functions

If $f(a)+f(-b)=0$ for some $(a,b)$, then, $f(-a)+f(b)=0$.

Also, for all $a$, there exists $b$ such that $f(a)+f(-b)=0$.

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

Based on the above conditions, can we prove or disprove that $f$ is an odd function: $f(x)=-f(-x)$?

I think we cannot prove this. Being odd seems to be a sufficient but not necessary. Yet I failed to find any counterexamples against the claim.

---

Update: Thanks to user WhatsUp, even functions $f(x)=f(-x)$ can also satisfy these conditions.

User Kavi suggests that if we add $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, then $f$ is odd. (please correct me if I am wrong) I will make a new question based on his intuition.

Comment: What are domain and range of $f$?

Comment: @Mastrem Ok I will update. But your example seems violate the second condition.

Comment: Good point, I misread

Comment: The first sentence seems to mean that there is one pair such that $f(a)+f(-b)=0$ and $f(-a)+f(b)=0$.

Comment: @Woody3 It means if $f(a)+f(-b)=0$ then $f(-a)+f(b)=0$. Let me update the question to clarify

Comment: This implication is (vacuously)  true for any strictly positive  function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But $f$ cannot be strictly positive, since it is given there exist $a,b$ with $f(a)+f(-b)=0$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You mean we need to add a restriction that $f(x)>0$ whenever $x>0$?

Comment: So you can collapse both statement as $\forall a:\exists b:f(a)+f(-b)=0=f(-a)+f(b)$.

Comment: @Woody3 I guess not? The first condition is for all $a$ for all $b$, if $f(a)+f(-b)=0$, then $f(-a)+f(b)=0$

Comment: @dodo: the is ambiguity in the formulation. *for some* vs. *for all*.

Comment: For any *even* function, $f(a)+f(-b)=0\implies f(-a)+f(b)=0$.

Comment: @Woody3 Yes you are right. So Kavi also made a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite simple counterexample is $f(x) = \cos(x)$.

Comment: Ok it seems like any even function also satisfies these conditions. Good point!

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall a ~ \exists b: f(a)+f(-b)=0  $$
Choose $a=0$. There exists $b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)+f(-b)=0$

From the first condition, $f(0)+f(b)=0$
$$ \therefore \exists b \in \mathbb{R} :f(b) = f(-b)$$
Thus, your function is certainly not odd.

Comment: What about $b=0$ and $f(0)=f(0)$? If $f$ is an odd function then $f(0)=0$